# Django day and month event date query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model that looks like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(...etc...)
    date = model.DateField(...etc...)
```

What I need is a way to get all events that are on a given day and month - much like an "on this day" page.

```
def on_this_day(self,day,month):
    reutrn Events.filter(????)
```

I've tried all the regular date query types, but they all seem to require a year, and short of iterating through *all* years, I can't see how this could be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a query like this by specifying the day and the month:

```
def on_this_day(day, month):
    return Event.objects.filter(date__day=day, date__month=month)
```

It most likely *scans* your database table using SQL operators like `MONTH(date)` and `DAY(date)` or some lookup equivalent

You might get a better query performance if you add and index `Event.day` and `Event.month` (if `Event.date` is internally stored as an `int` in the DB, it makes it less adapted to your `(day, month)` queries)

Here's some docs from Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month