# Trying to Write a Django Query That Counts Events Per Day For Events That Span Multiple Days

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I am using Django and trying to count the number of events that are running on each day based on events running across multiple days. For example, if Event 1 starts on Monday and ends on Wednesday and Event 2 starts on Tuesday and ends on Thursday, the event count per day should be: Monday (1 event), Tuesday (2 events), Wednesday (2 events), Thursday (1 event). The event model looks like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True) 
   start_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
   end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

I would like to get query results to include the date of the day we are counting for, the number of events running on that day, and the name of each event running on that day. Any help on this Django query would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think its possible to do what you are wanting to do here via queryset. You need to use pythonic ways to achieve it

Comment: @ruddra, any Pythonic way suggestions? :)

Comment: Bạn tham khảo bài này: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708749/django-day-and-month-event-date-query

Comment: Or fetch all the objects with the minimum information required (only 'start_date' and 'end_date' fields) and count using Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the count for a particular date, we can do something like this:

```
from datetime import date

target_date = date.today()    # Change this according to your needs.

todays_events = Event.objects.filter(
    start_date__date__lte=target_date,    # 'start_date__lte=target_date' if 'start_date' is a 'DateField'.
    end_date__date__gte=target_date,      # 'end_date__gte=target_date' if 'end_date' is a 'DateField'.
).count()
```

---

**You might want to read: [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference). It has lots of examples.**

---

To find for all dates, fetch all the objects with the `minimum information required` and count using Python.

```
events = Event.objects.all().only('start_date', 'end_date')    # Only fetch 'start_date' and 'end_date' fields.
```

Write your code in Python.

Comment: How would this work when there is no target date? I want to return the count per day for all events in the database so the day would be everyday that is between the start and end dates of all events.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check!